# Install 100 amp sub panel

Tags: electrical, garage

Going from outside box to 100 amp square d box. someone said put a double 60 in main box, use 6/3 wire to sub panel. I need to know how wiring looks in square d box. Building codes not issue. can add pic if told how. Distance is 25 feet. thanks

Comment: Size of the sub panel is not limited, so a couple bucks more for a 200 amp panel might be better.  It is the amount available from the main panel that set the feeder breaker size.  Do a load calculation if main panel powers other stuff, then that will size the feeder breaker which will size the wires needed.

Comment: Is the new box in the same building the outside box is on, or in a different building?